# Mediator pattern passing data php

Tags: php

```
class Mediator {
    protected $events = array();
    public function attach($eventName, $callback) {
        if (!isset($this->events[$eventName])) {
            $this->events[$eventName] = array();
        }
        $this->events[$eventName][] = $callback;
    }
    public function trigger($eventName, $data = null) {
        foreach ($this->events[$eventName] as $callback) {
            $callback($eventName, $data);
        }
    }
}
$mediator = new Mediator;
$mediator->attach('stop', function() { echo "Stopping"; });
$mediator->attach('stop', function() { echo "Stopped"; });
$mediator->trigger('stop'); // prints "StoppingStopped"
```

I can't figure out how I can successfully pass data to the pattern, i.e. I would want to pass the database object, but it ends up like this.

```
$mediator->attach('test', function($test) { echo $test; });
$mediator->trigger('test', '123');
```

It prints out "test", not 123.

Comment: Looks like you are doing an event system via Mediator pattern. But where are the listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to replace :

```
$callback($eventName, $data);
```

With

```
$callback($data);
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/11379)